# Why is my virtualhost defaulting to the standard document root?

Tags: dns, apache2, ubuntu-12.04, virtualhost

I have two domains registered: **example.com** and **example.org**. For one of these, I have also registered a subdomain: **sub.example.com**.

I successfully managed to set up a virtual host for my subdomain sub.example.com. So example.com points to the default document root `/var/www` and sub.example.com points to `/var/www/sub.example.com`.

But for some reason, I can't get example.org to point to anything else than the default document root. So example.com and example.org leads to the same website. I have created a virtual host for example.org, but Apache doesn't seem to register it.

```
# /etc/apache2/sites-available/example.org

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin admin@example.org
    ServerName example.org
    DocumentRoot /var/www/example.org
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you enabled the website?

With `a2ensite example.org` you can enable your site. Then do `service apache2 reload` to reload the websites.

Comment: Thank you! That was indeed the issue. I will mark this answer as correct in 6 minutes.